# Oracle SQL calculating to the nearest 1st of the month IN ADDITION to a determined amount of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to create an Oracle SQL statement that can work based on first of the month conditions. Dates are murdering me because their formatting is very specific.

Essentially, if a date isn't the first of the month I need to count the days until the next first of the month.

So lets say if I had a wait period of 54 days and 54 days didn't land on a first of the month condition, I need to add the remaining days until the next first of the month. So it'd be 54 days PLUS the remaining days until the next first day of the month. I'm using the below statement to calculate days remaining for me.

current_date and sysdate I've been using interchangably.

`ROUND((ENROLLDT-CURRENT_DATE + WAITPRD),1) AS WAIT_DAYS)`

Enrolldt is a date someone "enrolls" for a service - sysdate/current_date so we can get the amount of time passed by already + waitprd [which is "activation wait period after enrollment" that is an integer value]. So for example, someone can enroll on 5/5 with a 90 day wait period which would be August 3rd but if they have a first of the month condition it would be September 1st. So if we were to do today 5/7, it'd be 88 days + the new first of the month calculation from there.

I've also been playing with
`ROUND((((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), +1)))-SYSDATE),1)`
That's to calculate the remaining days from now, to the next first of the month but something isn't clicking when I try to combine these together because date formatting is new to me (obviously).

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Formatting isn't relevant for date manipulation, only for display. Your title says 'nearest' and you use `round()`, but it looks like you always round *up*, unless your adjusted date is the 1st anyway, right? Some representative sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: There is something wrong from the start in your computations. Assuming that the "enrollment date" was before **sysdate** and you must count to see how many days of the "waiting period" have already passed, you must subtract the enrollment date from **sysdate**, but you are doing it the other way around. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to work out a variable number of days to adjust by, you can manipulate the end of the wait period using `trunc()` and `add_months()` (or interval addition):

```
add_months(trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM'), 1)
```

So with your example enrol date of 2021-05-05 and wait period of 90 days:

- enrolldt + waitprd = 2021-08-03
- enrolldt + waitprd - 1 = 2021-08-02
- trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM') = 2021-08-01
- add_months(trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM'), 1) = 2021-09-01

The -1 is there to handle when the wait period ends on the first of the month. For example, if the enrol date was 2021-04-08 and wait period was 54:

- enrolldt + waitprd = 2021-06-01
- enrolldt + waitprd - 1 = 2021-05-31
- trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM') = 2021-05-01
- add_months(trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM'), 1) = 2021-06-01

Then, if I'm following that part, your wait calculation is just:

```
add_months(trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM'), 1) - trunc(sysdate)
```

giving 177 and 25 respectively for those two examples when run today.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=813dc6fec558ff36a868c69f178350b7) with some sample values covering month end/start.

You could use a case expression to decide whether to adjust based on whether it's already on the first, but I think it's simpler to just always do it.

---

As @mathguy pointed out, if you aren't already filtering them out somehow then some past enrol date/wait period calculations could give you a negative result, and you can use `greatest()` to avoid negative numbers, replacing them with zero:

```
greatest(0, add_months(trunc(enrolldt + waitprd - 1, 'MM'), 1) - trunc(sysdate))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=908766aa8e520fe0c803ce64f1c6ac10) with an example.

Comment: The "wait calculation" is likely `greatest(0, --your calculation--)` (to account for the possibility that the wait period has already ended).

Comment: I'm learning so much from this, thank you for the assistance. This was exactly what I was looking for. 

Also, this dbfiddle is really cool.